# Mysql data entries older then MAX(date)

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one with devices and on with corresponding service times. Each device can have several services. I'm looking for devices which last service is older than 3 Months. I tried this, which of course didn't work:

```
SELECT devices.id, 
       devices.name,  
       services.servicetime 
FROM devices
    LEFT JOIN services 
        ON services.device_id = devices.id
WHERE MAX(services.servicetime) < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH);
```

How con i get the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `GROUP BY devices.id` to your query, and change the condition to a `HAVING` clause (evaluated after grouping). You want the `MAX(services.servicetime)` *per device*, where your current result set includes one row per service.

```
SELECT
  devices.id,
  devices.name,
  MAX(services.servicetime)
FROM
  devices
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  services
ON
  services.device_id = devices.id
GROUP BY
  devices.id
HAVING
  MAX(services.servicetime) < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
```

If you want to include devices that have never been serviced, then add `OR MAX(services.servicetime) IS NULL` to the end.

Comment: FYI: Other RDBMS would require GROUP BY on both `devices.id, devices.name`. Only MySQL allows ambiguity

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT devices.id, devices.name, MAX(services.servicetime)
FROM 
    devices
    LEFT JOIN
    services ON services.device_id=devices.id
GROUP BY
    devices.id, devices.name
HAVING
    MAX(services.servicetime) < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
    OR
    MAX(services.servicetime) IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select devices.id,devices.name.services.servicetime from devices,services
where services.id = devices.id and services.id in 
(select services.id from services where
 DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) GROUP by services.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

[GROUP BY and HAVING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html) is your clause:

```
SELECT devices.id, devices.name, max(services.servicetime) FROM devices
LEFT JOIN services ON services.device_id=devices.id
GROUP BY devices.id, devices.name
HAVING MAX(services.servicetime) < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH);
```